# Running Power Automate with dataverse virtual tables

Tags: powerapps

I’m currently trying to run a flow on Microsoft Power Automate that requires a trigger when there’s  a CUD operation in one of my tables from Dataverse.
My aim is to trigger an event once a new occurrence happens on mshr_recruitingrequest (from Microsoft Human Resources).

Once I test the flow, the following error (details) are displayed:
“*Data events are not enabled for this virtual table. VirtualEntityMetadata configuration is missing.*”
[image: Power Automate Error]

I’ve looked for the solution on the web, and apparently, following the recommendation of Microsoft (Enable Virtual Tables to support Dataverse events (Microsoft Dataverse) - Power Apps | Microsoft Docs) I need to make some change to the solution on make.powerapps.com. Although there’s a problem, because this is a managed solution (native from MS), and when I try to edit the Dynamics 365 HR Virtual Entities to add Virtual Entity Metadata, I immediately see the following message:
“*You cannot directly edit the components within a managed solution. If the managed properties for solution components are set to allow customization, you can edit them from another unmanaged solution.*”
(see picture below)
[image: PowerApps]

What would be the solution entitling me to edit the components? Or if there’s none, what are the alternatives?

Thanks,

CryptoFFM

Comment: You have access to Data Events in F&O? you can enable from there and this will enable OnExternalCreated, ...Updated, ...Deleted events in Dataverse.

Answer (score 0):

[Explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/human-resources/hr-admin-integration-common-data-service-virtual-entities)

If you look at the comparison section, the HR stuff isn't native DataVerse. You could use Business rules, Processes or other stuff to create what you are looking for.